# One-to-one based on condition

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Voting(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice = models.ForeignKey(Choice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answered_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

It works as expected, however, a user is not supposed to be able to vote on the same question twice. In other words, the user shouldn't have the ability to vote twice on the same question:

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=120)

class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Is there a way to add this condition on a model level?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can not add a `constraint` for that, since most databases do not allow to "follow" `FOREIGN KEY`s.

What you could do is check it there is a `Voting` object already for the given `user` and the `question` related to the `choice`:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class Voting(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice = models.ForeignKey(Choice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answered_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if Voting.objects.exclude(
            pk=self.pk
        ).filter(
            user_id=self.user_id,
            choice__answer__choice__id=self.choice_id
        ).exists():
            raise ValidationError('You can not vote twice on the same question')
        return super().clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

Note that a model does *not* perform validation itself when saving. You can call [**`.full_clean()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean) for example to check the constraints. Furthermore a `ModelForm` will perform the validation checks if you validate the form.

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't this better be implemented in an overridden save method? Instead of calling the clean method each time?